# Корректное название usb-выключателя

Tags: usb, электроника

Есть задумка, передать управление светом, вентилятором на пк. Реализация планируется через юсб. То есть, нужен выключатель (тупо закоротить), но вот проблемка: ни в гугле ни в алике не нашёл нужного.
Суть устройства: коннектится к пк через юсб и програмное воздействие на устройство (запись-чтение из файла, как альтенатива, либо команда на компорт) заставляет оное включить-выключить что-либо (желательна возможность регулировать постоянно включено-выключено).
Хотелось бы корректное название для покупки (типа usb-switcher), прямо тыкнуть носом тоже хорошо.
Либо не сложная схема данного устройства.

Comment: для умного дома usb-выключатель - это дичь. По беспроводному каналу намного больше устройств

Comment: эммм, нет. пусть требуется включение вайфай роутера...

Comment: Электросхема вам не поможет, нужна еще и программа для управления всем.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самое простое устройство, реализующее вашу хотелку - преобразователь USB-UART на базе микросхемы FT232 или CP2103
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно считывать состояние линий (Сигнал RTS) последовательного порта или использовать возможности драйвера этих микросхем, который позволяет работать со всеми восемью (или 12-ю в случае CP2103) выводами в режиме GPIO

Нужно понимать, что сам адаптер имеет небольшую мощность на своих выходах, так что для сопряжения с нагрузкой потребуются силовые приборы - транзисторы, симисторы, реле или контакторы, в зависимости от задачи.